# How to highlight every tag whichs attribute ends with something

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following html list:

```
<li class=​"info" data-info=​"" data-title=​"info 1" data-info-id=​"222643">​…​</li>​ 
<li class=​"info" data-info=​"" data-title=​"info 2" data-info-id=​"217145">​…​</li>​ 
<li class=​"info" data-info=​"" data-title=​"info 3" data-info-id=​"114942">​…​</li>​ 
<li class=​"info" data-info=​"" data-title=​"info 4" data-info-id=​"268474">​…​</li>​ 
<li class=​"info" data-info=​"" data-title=​"info 5" data-info-id=​"288901">​…​</li>​ 
<li class=​"info" data-info=​"" data-title=​"info 6" data-info-id=​"127051">​…​</li>​
```

and i'm using the following javascript the get the data-info-id

```
var information = $('.info');
var array = [];

information.each(function() {
  array.push($(this).attr('data-info-id'));
});

var joined = array.join('||');
console.log(joined);
```

Which gives me the list of the data-info-id

I would like to highlight the data-info-id which are only ending in 1 (which are the last 2 items)

Answer (score 2):

Let me google that for you ;)

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 var totalElems = document.getElementsByTagName('li').length; 
  for(var i =0;i<=totalElems; i++) {
    var elem = document.querySelectorAll('li[data-info-id$="1"]');
    elem[i].style.color = 'red';
  }
```

I have added a DEMO too:

**http://jsbin.com/xucakirici/2/**